# Substitute for an electrical clamp, when the wiring is already connected

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, code-compliance

I have some old-work can lights in my ceiling, and they don't have the clamps around the wires where they enter the can, like they should to meet code. In other words, they **don't** have these:

[image]

Is there a substitute for these clamps that I can use, that meets code and doesn't require me to disconnect the wiring to install such item?

Comment: Are you certain there is _no_ clamping mechanism at all? Perhaps there is a cable clamp and you're not recognizing it. A picture of one of the actual boxen in question might help someone here recognize an existing clamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of plastic connectors out there that you can use to correct your problem.  One such one is shown below from Granger.  You can insert them from both sides of the box/fixture after placing the cable into the connector.

[image]

Comment: Of note, there is a slice in the side of the connector that would allow it to be slipped over the housing prior to being pushed into the knockout. (In case it's not obvious how you'd get this around the cable in the first place.)